# Black screen on bootup, after installing steam

Tags: 16.04, graphics, display, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I am getting black screen before login(that is, after the Ubuntu loading thing is done). This started when I installed steam(which installed Oibaf's drivers for display, which I cannot use). I tried to manually remove most of the drivers, reversed a bunch of stuff but I believe that not everything is reverted.

Edit:
doing "inxi -G" in tty4 returns 2 cards , and next line is:
display server: N/A driver: failed: Intel tty size:240x67 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

Comment: To the bets of my knowledge, the only way to install the oibaf drivers is to have added the PPA for oibaf - the package `steam` does not seem to include anything spcific to oibaf.  How did you install steam?

Comment: I don't know, steam installed it itself. After installing steam I found oibaf's ppa added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved. Appears I had uninstalled ubuntu-desktpp somewhere in the process.
I ran

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

and a bunch of other basic installs ( which I cannot remember, but will keep it posted as soon as I find it :( )